# Do I have to take my time while learning to code?

Tags: html, css

Is it better to take some time while learning to program in general or is it better to jump swiftly over the topics and try to reach some fruition?

I started web development course on Coursera. The first course that covers HTML,CSS and JavaScript was more or less bearable. It were the basics. Bootstrap was kinda hard. And I have to confess, I don't fully understand JavaScript. Now I am on AngularJS course. And I am stuck. I do not understand anything. Although I spend approximately four to five months of learning web development in general. So, my question is: "Should I thoroughly learn the concepts while reading some books on HTML/CSS/JavaScript and AngularJS or is it better try to finish the course without diving deep into the subject?" Should I be Jack of all trades or Master of the subjecdt?

Comment: I feel you Aanatoly_ ... just do a basic javascript (https://br.udacity.com/course/javascript-basics--ud804/) web course and you will be fine

Comment: Thank you Rafael for your understanding. I read some books on the subject right now. But I definitely going to check out some courses on JavaScript. I realized that time is the cure for everything, including lack of my intelligence. I strive not to give up. Learning all by myself is difficult. And there is no one in my city interested in Programming as I am.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While taking courses on Coursera it is **absolutely essential** that you  understand the core concepts before you move on to the next course. Don't try to rush yourself - and feel free to try out things that are not included in your assignments.

Working with AngularJS without understanding Javascript is close to impossible.

Comment: Don't answer off topic questions